# AuraError: Error at new Aura.externalLibraries

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, rest-api, locker-service

**Background**

I am using this approach [Call REST API from Lightning Components without Named Credentials](https://github.com/douglascayers/sfdx-lightning-api-component) to call the Salesforce REST API from a Lightning component.

It works when I call this URL:

```
/services/data/v45.0/tabs
```

But when I make this call:

```
    cmp.find('lc_api').restRequest({
        'url': '/services/data/v45.0/appMenu/AppSwitcher',
        'method': 'get',
        'body': null
    }).then($A.getCallback(function (apps) {
        cmp.set('v.apps', apps);
    })).catch($A.getCallback(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }));
```

I get this error:

> Error at new Aura.externalLibraries (https://static.lightning.force.com/cs87/auraFW/javascript/0Rz6fp7Oruhim-Qzw_AgRQ/aura_proddebug.js:26554:23) at ...

If i change the code to:

```
    cmp.find('lc_api').restRequest({
        'url': '/services/data/v45.0/appMenu/AppSwitcher',
        'method': 'get',
        'body': null
    }).then($A.getCallback(function (results) {
        let data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results))
        cmp.set('v.apps', data.appMenuItems);
    })).catch($A.getCallback(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }));
```

It works, because I am converting the response to a `String` and then back to an `Object`.

**Questions**

1. What is causing it?
2. Why do I need to so this sometimes and not others?